# How to make a coroutine wait on a second coroutine to finish before resuming?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am making a football simulation game in Unity, and I have a basic Player_Agent class to handle non-intelligent actions like running,jumping, etc. I have a coroutine Dive(Vector2 a_direction) where the agent should rotate to face a_direction and then move forwards until its height is back to its starting height. However, whenever I execute this coroutine, it will rotate to face a_direction but then just exit out of the Dive coroutine entirely.

Every post I found suggested to do it how I had it implemented, using `yield return StartCoroutine(TurnTo(Vector2 a_direction));`, and if I changed it to `StartCoroutine(TurnTo(a_direction)); yield return null;` then it will execute both routines simultaneously which is not the desired result. I tried it with both StartRoutine() and without it, and am kind of lost. Am I not trying to implement this correctly or is it just a syntax error?

MVP:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player_Agent : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Dynamic Variables
    //--------------------------------------------------

    public float w_speed;
    public float w_height;
    public Vector2 w_direction;

    // Member Variables
    //--------------------------------------------------

    /// <summary></summary>
    public float m_speed; // Set to 5 in unity editor
    public float m_acceleration; // Set to 1 in unity editor
    public float m_vertical; // Set to 1 in unity editor

    public float m_height; // Set to 2 in unity editor

    // --------------------------------------------------
    //  GAMEPLAY METHODS
    // --------------------------------------------------
    #region Gameplay Methods


    /// <summary>
    /// Turns the agent towards the target direction
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a_direction">A unit vector representing the desired result for w_direction </param>
    /// <returns>A coroutine of the agent turning </returns>
    public IEnumerator TurnTo(Vector2 a_direction)
    {
        // Initialize helper variables
        Vector2 t_direction_0 = w_direction;
        float t_time = Time.deltaTime;
        float t_angle = Mathf.Atan2(a_direction.y, a_direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Quaternion t_quat_0 = transform.rotation;
        Quaternion t_quat_1 = Quaternion.AngleAxis(t_angle, Vector3.forward);

        // While not facing the correct direction
        while (w_direction != a_direction)
        {
            // Use slerp to dynamically rotate and change w_direction
            Quaternion t_quat = Quaternion.Slerp(t_quat_0,t_quat_1,t_time);
            transform.rotation = t_quat;
            w_direction = (t_quat * t_direction_0).normalized;

            yield return null;

            // Update time elapsed
            t_time += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // Ensure that there is no error
        w_direction = a_direction.normalized;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Turns the agent towards the target direction
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a_angle">A float between 0 and 360 representing the turning angle </param>
    /// <returns>A coroutine of the agent turning </returns>
    public IEnumerator TurnTo(float a_angle)
    {
        // Initialize helper variables
        Vector2 t_direction_0 = w_direction;
        float t_time = Time.deltaTime;
        Quaternion t_quat_0 = transform.rotation;
        Quaternion t_quat_1 = t_quat_0 * Quaternion.AngleAxis(a_angle, Vector3.forward);

        Debug.Log("Turning");

        // While not facing the correct direction
        while (transform.rotation != t_quat_1)
        {
            // Use slerp to dynamically rotate and change w_direction
            Quaternion t_quat = Quaternion.Slerp(t_quat_0, t_quat_1, t_time);
            transform.rotation = t_quat;
            w_direction = (t_quat * t_direction_0).normalized;

            yield return null;

            // Update time elapsed
            t_time += Time.deltaTime;
        }

    }

    public IEnumerator Dive(Vector2 a_direction)
    {
        // Initialize helping variables
        float t_height = m_height + m_vertical * Time.deltaTime;
        float t_time = Time.deltaTime;
        Vector2 t_position_0 = (Vector2)transform.position;
        Vector2 t_position = new Vector2(t_position_0.x, t_position_0.y);
        bool hasJumped = false;
        Coroutine t_coroutine;

        // If not facing a_direction
        if (w_direction != a_direction)
        {
            // Turn towards a_direction
            yield return StartCoroutine(TurnTo(a_direction));
        }

        
        // While the agent hasn't jumped and is stil in the air
        while ((t_height - m_height) > 0.01f || hasJumped == false)
        {
            // Update w_height and position
            w_height = t_height;
            transform.position = t_position;

            yield return null;

            // Update t_time and t_height
            t_time += Time.deltaTime;
            t_height = m_height + 2.5f * m_vertical * 0.7071f * t_time - 4.9f * Mathf.Pow(t_time, 2);
            t_position = t_position_0 + (m_vertical + w_speed) * t_time * a_direction;
            Debug.Log(t_height);
            // Flip hasJumped flag
            if (!hasJumped) { hasJumped = true; }
        }

        // Reset w_height
        w_height = m_height;
    }

    #endregion


}
```

Note: obviously not a finished or polished setup, but this is a pattern I have occurring in several more of my planned methods and I wanna make sure I'm implementing it right before I do so.

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to do it.

`1` **Calling the second coroutine inside the first**

```
IEnumerator routine1(){
    print("routine1: Calling routine2");
    yield return routine2();
    print("routine1: routine2 ended");
}

IEnumerator routine2(){
    print("routine2: Waiting 1 second");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    print("routine2: 1 second passed");
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
routine1: Calling routine2
routine2: Waiting 1 second
routine2: 1 second passed
routine1: routine2 ended
```

---

`2` **Calling them at distict times**

```
bool routine2ended = false;

IEnumerator routine1(){
    print("routine1: Let's wait routine2");
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => routine2ended);
    print("routine1: routine2 ended");
}

IEnumerator routine2(){
    print("routine2: Waiting 1 second");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    print("routine2: 1 second passed");
    routine2ended = true;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
routine1: Let's wait routine2
routine2: Waiting 1 second
routine2: 1 second passed
routine1: routine2 ended
```

Comment: Actually there is not even need to start a coroutine for the inner one .. simply yield return the `IEnumerator` directly: `yield return routine2();`

Comment: If you are sure of that, feel free to edit my answer. I'm not in Unity atm and I always used sequential coroutines like I wrote (using `yield return StartCoroutine(routine2())`).

Comment: Both do basically the same thing, yes ;) In general yield return another IEnumerator (not even Coroutine and Unity specific) you basically just extend your enumeration :)

Comment: I know I’m a year late on this, but thank you for your awesome answer!